# Why is the rendered picture not the same as in rendered mode?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Why is the rendered picture not the same as in rendered mode? The first one less than the second one[image]

Comment: Doesn't appear that your image attached inline - can you add it again so we can see?

Comment: I cant upload that image im  just trying

Comment: @CraigDJones done can you see this

Comment: Is the object in white using a modifier, and have you set your scene to simplify? In modifiers there are settings sometimes for different levels of subdivision at render time versus viewport, etc.

Comment: How can i simplify that scene and again i didnt apply modifiers whith that couses problem ?

Comment: Please use print screen to make screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is if you use a modifier that has separate settings for viewport and render like in Subdivision Surface modifier:

[image]

Also possible is to set simplification of the scene for animation while rendering at full settings:

[image]