Rendering and viewport in Cycles does not match with each other
I am new to Blender.
I have setup animation but when I am viewing it in render view it has everything ideal for me the lights the blocks everything is ok.
But once I render it everything is getting spoiled starting from lights
This one is what is rendered

This is what I see in rendered viewport

Link to Blender FIle
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VnQque_VOXhUn15eJh1SyGBik6LoPiGT/view?usp=drive_link
Can someone help with this ?

On the Grid objects (deformed planes) you are instancing cubes. But the grids have a Subdivision Surface modifier. By default, it has 1 level for the viewport and 2 levels for the render. That's bad in your case because in render you get a lot more cubes that also intersect and overlap. To fix it, just set the render levels to 1.

the question is a duplicate of these questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/169210/107598 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/142016/107598 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/131559/107598 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/244623/107598

definitely light samples, try to make it higher or lower grain. if this doesn't fix it then just render in evee like a boss.

Hi @Kaleb Claussen, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment."
